# How to change the color of the text after clicking on it in Squarespace?

Tags: javascript, css, squarespace

How to change the color of the text after clicking on it in Squarespace?

Where in the code do I insert the block id to target a particular block?

Here is the code I was trying to use

```
<script>

    document.getElementById('change').onclick = changeColor;   

    function changeColor() {
        document.body.style.color = "purple";
        return false;
    }   

</script>
```

I need some help with JavaScript

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java. Please don't tag-spam.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the CSS on the DOM element you want to style not on the `document.body`.

Just as a side note, nowadays it's preferred to use an [eventlistener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for things like this since it doesn't completely override a property of an element. (`onclick` in this case)

```js
const element = document.getElementById('change');

function changeColor() {
  element.style.color = "purple";
}

element.onclick = changeColor;

// or
// element.addEventListener("click", changeColor);
```

```html
<p id="change">This should change onclick</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Where exactly to I insert the block ID?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

---

```
document.getElementById("foo").onclick = funciton {changeColor()};

function changeColor(){
    document.getElementById("foo").style.color = "#00ff00";
}
```

you can change "foo" to anything you want but it needs to be unique.

Comment: Is this the way code would look like with the block id and color inserted? 


<div id="#block-87bb744eebfb16c3f9ad"></div>
document.getElementById("#block-87bb744eebfb16c3f9ad").onclick = funciton {changeColor()};

function changeColor(){
    document.getElementById("#block-87bb744eebfb16c3f9ad").style.color = "#bfafa6";
}

Answer (score 0):

Put the ID of the CSS selector you're targeting as an attribute in the HTML element.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="para">Some text here</p>
    <button onclick="changeColor('blue');">blue</button>
    <button onclick="changeColor('red');">red</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Within the java script it would be like this

```
function changeColor(newColor) {
  const elem = document.getElementById("para");
  elem.style.color = newColor;
}
```

> Source:
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById